# Docker: Export and Import

Tags: docker

I made archive of my docker's container.

- docker export ID > container.tar

then I've tried to make import of this archive

- docker import conteiner.tar

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "sleep": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

I've tried to make image from container. Save my options.

Comment: IME it's very unusual to use `docker export` at all.  Just `docker run` a new container when you need it.

Comment: Export the container to a container.tar file with the export command
Stop the container
Delete the image with docker rmi [image_id|repository]without removing the container first
Delete stopped container
Import the container back using the importcommand. It is my task.

Comment: Right, there are a handful of Docker commands you pretty much never use (`import`, `export`, `commit`).  What's your higher-level goal; why are you trying to run these commands at all?